# Removing some dependencies from package.json in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I'm new to Laravel need to know few things, In `package.json` file of Laravel 5.3 there are few dependencies which I don't want to install and I also don't know what are these for

```
" lodash "
" laravel-elixir-webpack-official "
"laravel-elixir-vue"
"vue": "^1.0.26"
"vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
"jquery": "^3.1.0"
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7"
```

If I remove these, will it affect any other things in my Laravel project? Or will I have to remove something in some other file too linked to these dependencies? Actually I just wanna use Elixir so I don't know if some of these dependencies are linked to Elixir.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: I believe anything which comes under `require-dev` can be removed, but anything which comes under `require` must not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Laravel.

As I observed from your package.json file, your packages are completely dependent on each other except `"jquery": "^3.1.0"` and "`bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7"`.

Basically, a package comes with some dependencies which they have been told in documentations.

Comment: so it means elixir won't work if i delete some of them ?

Comment: if you want to use `vue` in parallel of your elixir no in won't work, if you don't you can just include `lodash` and `laravel-elixir-webpack-official`

Comment: yeah i don't wanna use vue so can i remove it ? and btw what are `lodash` and `laravel-elixir-webpack-official` for? actually i just need to run simple task like concate, minify and complie saas nothing more so i guess it useless to have all dependencies installed or maybe i am wrong

Comment: @user3780848 Yeah you can remove the. Actually `lodash` is a library which brings some api and helpers for JS and regardless of the use of `laravel-elexir-webpack-official` from `lodash`  it could be beneficial if you keep using it.